# Terraform Modules not working as expected

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We are using a private Github and Terraform Cloud for our projects. Everything is able to talk to each other so there is no issue there. However, I'm trying to create modules for a project I started. I was able to make it work as regular terraform files, but when I try to convert to the module system I am having issues with getting the state imported.

We have a separate repository called tf-modules. In this repository, my directory setup:

```
> root 
>> mymodule
>>> lambda.tf
>>> eventbridge.tf
>>> bucket.tf
```

These files manage the software being deployed in our AWS environment. They are being used across multiple environments for each of our customers (each separated out by environment [qa, dev, prod]).

In my terraform files, I have:

```
> root
>> CUSTNAME
>>> mymodule
>>>> main.tf
```

Inside main.tf I have:

```
module "mymodule" {
  source = "git::https://github.com/myprivaterepo/tf-modules.git"
}
```

In my dev environment, everything is set up so I need to import the state. However, it's not detecting the resources at all. In the .terraform directory, it is downloading the entire repository (the root with the readme.md and all)

I'm fairly new to Terraform. Am I approaching this wrong or misunderstanding?

I am using the latest version of Terraform.

Comment: I am kind of confused. For example , is the repo URL correct based on the repo structure? This is important when calling modules. The second issue is if you have created resources manually, you still have to define code in Terraform for those resources and only then run import. They will not be created automagically just because a module has been specified.

Comment: If I understood the structure of your `tf-modules` repo correctly, there is no `.tf` file in the repo root. If that's the case current module import won't work as Terraform will look for a `.tf` file in the ROOT level. Take a look at [Modules in Package Sub-directories](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/sources#modules-in-package-sub-directories) on how to use the repo with `.tf` file in the subdirectories.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess this should work? `source = "git::https://github.com/myprivaterepo/tf-modules.git//mymodule"`

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a sub-directory "mymodule", you should specify the whole path.

```
module "mymodule" {
      source = "git::https://github.com/myprivaterepo/tf-modules.git//mymodule"
    }
```

Refer to [module sources - sub directory](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/sources#github)

Example: `git::https://example.com/network.git//modules/vpc`

Comment: Note that the `//` separator is important. If you just use a single `/` like in your current first example, Terraform will run `git clone https://github.com/myprivaterepo/tf-modules.git/mymodule` and that will probably fail unless the server has been designed to handle that in a special way somehow.

Comment: (Terraform does have some special additional heuristics for GitHub in particular that might make that particular example work, but I'd suggest showing it as `git::https://github.com/myprivaterepo/tf-modules.git//mymodule` so that the answer is more portable to other Git hosting platforms.)